# How do convert userID to an integer number in R?

Tags: r, string, integer, character, tidyverse

I have a dataset having column name "userID", where userID = (P001, P002, P010, P001, P010, P181).

I need to convert P001 equal to 1, P002 equal to 2, P010 equal to 10 and P181 equal to 181 and remain their vector position same as in dataset.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dataset$usernr <- as.integer(substr(dataset$userID, 2, 4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution

```
test <- c("P102","P103", "P001")
readr::parse_number(test)
[1] 102 103   1
```

Comment: @ Yuriy, Excellent solution ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all entries in the ID variable have the same format P+"some-numbers"

```
library(stringr)
test <- c("P102","P103", "P001" )
as.numeric( str_extract(test, "\\d+"))
[1] 102 103   1
```

Comment: should use as.integer, as suggested by by @jogo

Comment: @ desval, thank you very much. It also works for me.

Comment: @desval, there is a typo in the library name. I tried to edit your answer but the edit needs to be at least 6 characters. I think you mean "stringr" rather than "srtringr". :)

Comment: @desval no probs!